# Validation xml & xsd fail

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

When validate xml using schema and I have 2 schema , validation error

**line 10: Expected element 'fault@http://www.BM.org/FCUBS/Schemas/FullAccountList' instead of 'fault@http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/context' here
line 34: Expected element 'fault@http://www.BM.org/FCUBS/Schemas/FullAccountList' before the end of the content**

```
<FulAccLstResponse_elm xmlns="http://www.BM.org/FCUBS/Schemas/FullAccountList">
         <ResponseStatus>
            <Code>444</Code>
            <Description>Invalid Input Parameters</Description>
         </ResponseStatus>
         <ResponseData/>
         <con:fault xmlns:con="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/context">
            <con:errorCode>382505</con:errorCode>
            <con:reason>Validate action failed validation</con:reason>
            <con:details>
               <con1:ValidationFailureDetail xmlns:con1="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/stages/transform/config">
                  <con1:message>validation error</con1:message>
                  <con1:xmlLocation>
                     <IDFlag>NAtT</IDFlag>
                  </con1:xmlLocation>
                  <con1:message>Expected elements 'NationalId@http://www.BM.org/FCUBS/Schemas/FullAccountList CustomerId@http://www.BM.org/FCUBS/Schemas/FullAccountList' before the end of the content in element FulAccLstRequest_elm@http://www.BM.org/FCUBS/Schemas/FullAccountList</con1:message>
                  <con1:xmlLocation>
                     <ful:FulAccLstRequest_elm xmlns:ns0="http://www.BM.org/FCUBS/Schemas/FullAccountList" xmlns:ful="http://www.BM.org/FCUBS/Schemas/FullAccountList">
                        <ful:CallingSystem>sys</ful:CallingSystem>
                        <ful:UserName>user1</ful:UserName>
                        <ful:Branch>100</ful:Branch>
                        <ful:IDFlag>NAtT</ful:IDFlag>
                     </ful:FulAccLstRequest_elm>
                  </con1:xmlLocation>
               </con1:ValidationFailureDetail>
            </con:details>
            <con:location>
               <con:node>RouteNode1</con:node>
               <con:path>request-pipeline</con:path>
            </con:location>
         </con:fault>
      </FulAccLstResponse_elm>
```

- First Schema (import second schema)

```html
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.BM.org/FCUBS/Schemas/FullAccountList" elementFormDefault="qualified"
                xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.BM.org/FCUBS/Schemas/FullAccountList"
                 xmlns:con="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/context">
      <xsd:import schemaLocation="Fault.xsd"
                   namespace="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/context" />
      
      <xsd:complexType name="FulAccLstRequest_cpx">
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element name="IDFlag">
            <xsd:simpleType>
              <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                <xsd:enumeration value="CUST"/>
                <xsd:enumeration value="NAT"/>
              </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:simpleType>
          </xsd:element>
          <xsd:choice>
            <xsd:element name="NationalId" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="CustomerId" type="xsd:string"/>
          </xsd:choice>
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:complexType name="FulAccLstResponse_cpx">
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element name="ResponseStatus" type="FulAccLstResponseStatus_cpx"/>
          <xsd:element name="ResponseData" type="FulAccLstResponseData_cpx"/>
          <xsd:element name="fault" type="con:Fault_cpx" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:complexType name="FulAccLstResponseStatus_cpx">
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element name="Code" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element name="Description" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:complexType name="FulAccLstResponseData_cpx">
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element name="IFLEXAccountsStatus" type="xsd:string" default="0" minOccurs="0"/>
          <xsd:element name="IFLEXAccounts" type="FulAccLstUBSAccounts_cpx" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:complexType name="FulAccLstUBSAccounts_cpx">
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element name="Stvw-Account-Sumary-IO" type="QueryAccSumm-Query-IO-Type" minOccurs="0"/>
          <xsd:element name="Stvw-Account-Sumary-Full" type="QueryAccSumm-Full-Type" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:complexType name="QueryAccSumm-Full-Type">
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element name="CUST_NO" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
          <xsd:element name="Stvw-Account-Sumary--A" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xsd:complexType>
              <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="CURRBAL" type="xsd:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xsd:element name="CUSTACNO" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xsd:element name="BRANCH_CODE" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xsd:element name="CCY" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xsd:element name="ACCOUNT_TYPE" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xsd:element name="CUSTOMER_NAME" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xsd:element name="AC_DESC" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
              </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:complexType name="QueryAccSumm-Query-IO-Type">
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element name="CUST_NO" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:element name="FulAccLstRequest_elm" type="FulAccLstRequest_cpx"/>
      <xsd:element name="FulAccLstResponse_elm" type="FulAccLstResponse_cpx"/>
    </xsd:schema>
```

Second schema

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/context" xmlns="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/context"
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xsd:element name="fault" type="Fault_cpx"/>
  <xsd:complexType mixed="true" name="Fault_cpx">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:any namespace="##any" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" processContents="lax"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:anyAttribute namespace="##any" processContents="lax"/>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You confuse the globally defined element `fault`, which is in `{http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/context}` namespace,
with the locally defined one, which is in `{http://www.BM.org/FCUBS/Schemas/FullAccountList}` namespace. Although, both these
`fault`s look like the same, they have the same only their local names. Otherwise, they are completely different elements!

Your second (imported) schema defines `fault` globally. After that, you may use it anywhere only by reference.
But as you specify it here:

```
  <xsd:complexType name="FulAccLstResponse_cpx">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="ResponseStatus" type="FulAccLstResponseStatus_cpx"/>
      <xsd:element name="ResponseData" type="FulAccLstResponseData_cpx"/>
      <xsd:element name="fault" type="con:Fault_cpx" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
```

that `fault` within the `FulAccLstResponse_cpx` type is the local one and, therefore, belongs to the schema's destination namespace.

To make your XML work, you should define that piece as follows:

```
  <xsd:complexType name="FulAccLstResponse_cpx">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="ResponseStatus" type="FulAccLstResponseStatus_cpx"/>
      <xsd:element name="ResponseData" type="FulAccLstResponseData_cpx"/>
      <xsd:element ref="con:fault" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
```

P.S.

The following links may be interesting for those working with XML schemas and WSDL:

- High-performance universal **XML Schema Documentation Generator with diagrams**: http://www.flexdoc.xyz/flexdoc-xml/xsddoc/
- The same for WSDL & XSD together: http://www.flexdoc.xyz/flexdoc-xml/wsdldoc/

If you value my participation on this site, please do not remove these links!